# офицальные обращения

Tags: этикет

Я бы хотел знать если в Русском понятия официальных форм обращения.  Как, на пример, было «Ваше Величие».  Я не имею ввиду обращения сказанные с целью перекланяться.  А с целью формальности.  Если они да существуют, можно ли получить указание на их список?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что вы имеете в виду под официальными формами обращения. Если затрудняетесь сформулировать на русском, привидите пример подобных обращений в других языках. Было огромное количество дореволюционных форм обращения в зависимости от титула "Ваше величество", "Ваше сиятельство", "Ваше благородие" и т. п. После 1917 г. они все упразднены.

Comment: I mean what would be an equivalent of a formal salutation in English.  For example, when formally addressing a mayor of a city, "your honor" is an appropriate form.  As another example, "your majesty" is the appropriate 2nd person salutatoin when addressing a British queen or king.  Post-soviet Russian is very new.  And I am wondering if new forms of salutations have been adapted for public officials and other distinguished individuals.

Comment: You can ask your question in English on [russian] site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То что вы называете официальными обращениями присутствует и в русском языке. При обращении к судье используется форма *"Ваша честь"*, заключённые при обращении к полицейским используют форму *"гражданин начальник"*, а военнослужащие обязаны обращаться друг другу по форме "товарищ [воинское звание]". Активно подобная система используется русской православной церковью, хотя дальше клириков эти формы не уходят. В остальных случаях официальной формой обращения является имя-отчество. Допускается вместо них использовать вариант *товарищ (господин(госпожа)) [фамилия]*, правда после распада СССР слово "товарищ" стали использовать реже, а "господин" имеет второе значение "хозяин", поэтому тоже не очень популярно, когда есть возможность вместо них используют звание того кого называют *профессор Петров*, *сержант Иванов*.

Comment: Наверное мне надо было добавить что я имел в виду штатские формы обращения.  Подозреваю что военное использование ранка как формы формального обращения принято в большинстве языков.  Хотя это тоже может иметь свои нюансы во флоте.  К примеру чтоб на корабле не было больше одного капитана.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich, на военном корабле может быть до пяти разновидностей капитанов. Основной формой официального обращения является употребение имени и отчества.

Answer (score 1):

Обращения, начинающиеся с "Ваше..." сохранились в Русской Православной Церкви, но каждое имеет альтернативный, обычный по форме вариант:

http://v-pobeda.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=122:2012-12-03-11-31-43&catid=39:2012-01-19-05-12-27&Itemid=65